# Android Studio как с помощью adb перейти на нужный шаг как при старте

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, appium, android-adb

При старте скрипта загружается вот эта страница в эмуляторе

> desired_caps["appActivity"] = "com.viber.voip.AddFriendActivity"

Нужно после определённых манипуляций возвращаться на эту же страницу,как это сделать быстро?
Чтобы загружалoсь сразу приложение на нужном месте как при старте,и не надо было долго кликать.

Пробовал вот так:

```
adb shell am start -a com.viber.voip.AddFriendActivity"
```

не работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы запустить необходимую активити, попробуйте вот такую команду:

```bsh
adb shell am start -n <package name>/com.viber.voip.AddFriendActivity
```

[Аргумент `-a` служит для передачи `intent action`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec)

Comment: adb shell am start -n com.viber.voip/com.viber.voip.AddFriendActivity -S    вот так сработало "-S" надо было

Comment: @AlexseyKr `-S` нужен для принудительной остановки приложения перед стартом активити